# Want to display the warning Icon in a correct position without creating new class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I'm having a error messages in different tabs in my UI screen.But in one of the TAB the warning icon is not displaying in the middle of the screen.And that screen tab contains 2 Lines of error message and other screen tabs are containing one line message.

I'm using common class for all the tabs if i change the   "style="margin-top:-6px" " from -6 to 0. The tab is displaying the icon in the correct position.but other screens are affecting due to this.

The 2 line error message needs 0px and other screens are needs -6px. So how can i do this with out creating separate classes for each tab

```
<div class="error-message-container" ng-show="workloadConfigurationErrorMessage != ''" style="height: auto;">
            <div class="error-message-content" >
                <img src="app-vrm/img/error-warning-icon.png" style="margin-top:-6px"/>
                <p>
                    <span translate="workloadconfiguration.view.SYSTEM_WARNING"></span><p> {{workloadConfigurationErrorMessage}}</p>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: you can use ngStyle and assign the values accordingly for each template dynamically

Comment: But,I'm using common class right? so if i need to use ngStyle ,don't i need to create separate classes for each tab.

Comment: are you using same controller for all the tabs?

Comment: if($scope.networkConfig["mgmtSelected"] == undefined || !$scope.networkConfig["mgmtSelected"]["option"]) {
   $scope.workloadConfigurationErrorMessage = $filter('translate')('workloadconfiguration.controller.MGMT_PRENETWORK_SELECTION_MESSAGE');
   return;
  }

Comment: This is a function for that message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
style="margin-top:-6px"
```

give

```
ng-style="myStyle"
```

and in the corresponding controllers give,

```
$scope.myStyle={};
$scope.myStyle.marginTop="-6px"; or $scope.myStyle.marginTop="0px";
```

which ever view applicable.
Hope, I answered your question.

Comment: Syntax error on token "=", >= expected           I'm receiving this error in this scope function scope . "myStyle.margin-top = "-6px"; "

Comment: $scope.myStyle.marginTop